# Substituting localization module for a customized specific one - Odoo community

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to prevent Odoo from installing a default `account` localization and install a customized one instead.

I was trying by adding specific module as `depends` but this module has `account` as a dependency, so if I for example choose, x country and language for my Odoo database, it still installs the default localization for that country and language.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

I was trying with this model:

```
from openerp import models, api
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class IrModuleModule(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.module.module'

@api.model
def search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, count=False):
    new_args = []
    for arg in args:
        if arg[0] == 'name' and arg[1] == '=' and arg[2] == 'l10n_cl':
            arg = list(arg)
            arg[2] = 'l10n_cl_base'
        elif arg[0] == 'name' and arg[1] == 'in' and 'l10n_cl' in arg[2]:
            arg = list(arg)
            arg[2] = [
                'l10n_cl_base' if x == 'l10n_cl' else x for x in arg[2]]
        new_args.append(arg)
    return super(IrModuleModule, self).search(
        new_args, offset, limit, order, count=count)
```

But still nothing

Any ideas?